# Can i modify data "protected" by a CRC16?

Tags: mac, crc

There are 100 bytes with a CRC16.  However I only know the first 50.

I want to change byte 5 from a known value X to another value Y, and fix up the CRC16 to be valid - without knowing bytes 50-100.

This is possible with the TCP checksum, because it's just  addition.  But CRC16 is a polynomial.  Is it still possible?

Comment: If you can control at least 2 of the first 50 bytes you can fix the CRC.

Comment: @CodesInChaos You mean via brute force, or can I solve it as an equation?

Comment: If you XOR two 100 byte strings with valid CRCs then the result has a valid CRC (possibly with a tweak if the CRC is inverted). You can calculate the values using Gaussian Elimination mod 2 without having to understand any extra maths. This works because addition mod 2 has essentially the same features as normal addition. But as @CodesInChaos says, you need to be allowed to change at least 16 bits of the rest of the 100 bytes to some arbitrary values to "fix up" the CRC.

Comment: If you post 100 bytes and identify which ones you want changed to what and which ones you don't care about I'll do a demo!

Comment: @John Both. Brute-force is cheap at only 16 bits. It's also possible to compute it directly, but I don't remember details. I used that to fix the CRC32 of files to an arbitrary value by modifying 4 consecutive bytes in one of my projects.

Comment: I hope my answer is demonstrative of the fact that CRC *cannot* be used to protect against an intelligent adversary. It's fantastic for transmission errors, but if you need this sort of protection, use a MAC instead (like HMAC).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. And quite efficient, too.

$\DeclareMathOperator{\crc}{crc}$CRC is linear, meaning $\crc(x \oplus y) = \crc(x) \oplus \crc(y)$, where $\oplus$ is [bitwise exclusive-or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Computer_science).

Suppose there's a message $m$ and we're given $\crc(m)$.

Linearity means we can effectively compute the difference in the CRC digest by computing the CRC of the difference. For example, $m \oplus 1$ is the message with the right-most bit flipped — that's how XOR works. Because of linearity

$$\crc(m \oplus 1) = \crc(m) \oplus \crc(1)$$

So by computing $\crc(1)$ and doing a little bitwise arithmetic, we can find the CRC digest for the message if we were to flip the rightmost bit... without knowing the original message at all.

The same principle applies to your question. If you know the first byte of the message is (for example) 15 and you want to change it to 8, then compute $15 \oplus 8 = 7$ and pad that value with zero bytes on the right so it lines up with the first byte of the message. Let the padded value be called $d$. Then compute $$\crc(m) \oplus \crc(d) = \crc(m \oplus d)$$ which will be the forged CRC value. The reason you right-pad with zero bytes is $x \oplus 0 = x$ for any $x$: XORing a value with zero doesn't change it.

Here's what $m \oplus d$ looks like, if it helps clarify:

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
                 & 15 & \text{unknown bytes} & (\leftarrow m) \\
          \oplus & 7 & \text{00 00 00 ...}  & (\leftarrow d) \\ \hline
                 & 8 & \text{(same) unknown bytes} \\
\end{array}
$$

(I realize using decimal instead of hex here may look a little weird, but oh well.)

The original message's first byte was 15. We wanted it to be 8 instead. We found $15 \oplus 8$ to be 7, so that's the value we right-pad with zeros, because the zeros won't affect the rest of the message. Linearity lets us pull off the trick. Of course, this technique works for any number of bytes, not just the first one.

(By the way: the need to right pad the difference with zero bytes is why we needed to know the length of the original message.)

Note: fgrieu's comment below about some CRCs having a weaker property is relevant, but doesn't materially affect the attack (set $z = 0$ in his comment to use the same attack essentially).

Comment: Many CRCs in actual use do not have the property that $\crc(x⊕y)=\crc(x)⊕\crc(y)$. Instead that have the weaker property that for any **three** messages $x$, $y$, $z$ **of equal length**, $\crc(x⊕y⊕z)=\crc(x)⊕\crc(y)⊕\crc(z)$. Look at section 2.2.7.4 of [X.25](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.25-199610-I/en), and consider the effect of the prescribed initialization value, and final complementation. Still the attack remains possible.

Comment: @fgrieu: Interesting! I wasn't aware of that. Fortunately, as you said, it doesn't seem to affect the basic gist of the above.

Comment: Indeed, CRC is *affine*, meaning it is linear plus (xor) a constant. For the purpose of message modification, the effect on the *differences* is linear. For example, XORing a fixed difference to the message always results in XORing the same value to the original CRC.